# add controls vertically instead of horizontally using flow layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I am adding checkboxes on `JPanel` in `FlowLayout` the checkboxes are being added horizontally.

I want to add checkboxes vertically on the Panel. What is the possible solution?

Comment: FlowLayout is doing what it suggests, flowing components left to right till it has no space and then goes on next line, with different layouts you can do what you need.

Comment: what layout i should use for it

Comment: I would suggest a [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Comment: @user714965 as much as google helps with doing UI work an understanding of how it does it is still important

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[image]

I hope what you are trying to achieve is like this. For this please use Box layout.

```
package com.kcing.kailas.sample.client;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Testing extends JFrame {

    private JPanel jContentPane = null;

    public Testing() {
        super();
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
        this.setTitle("JFrame");
    }

    private JPanel getJContentPane() {
        if (jContentPane == null) {
            jContentPane = new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setLayout(null);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            panel.setBounds(61, 11, 81, 140);
            panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            jContentPane.add(panel);

            JCheckBox c1 = new JCheckBox("Check1");
            panel.add(c1);
            c1 = new JCheckBox("Check2");
            panel.add(c1);
            c1 = new JCheckBox("Check3");
            panel.add(c1);
            c1 = new JCheckBox("Check4");
            panel.add(c1);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Testing frame = new Testing();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and the basic approach (use BoxLayout) differs from the earlier answer by @AbstractChaos in that .. ? Except being worse: null layout in contentpane? manual sizing/positioning of panel? nononono, don't. And what is the updateComponentTreeUI supposed to achieve here?

Comment: this answe is correct but too complex and outer of focus of problem

Comment: How can I align a single element to the right and have all else centered?

Answer (score 49):

I used a `BoxLayout` and set its second parameter as `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` and it worked for me:

```
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: How can I align a single element to the right and have all else centered?

Answer (score 15):

As I stated in comment i would use a box layout for this.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout());

JButton button = new JButton("Button1");
button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
panel.add(button);

button = new JButton("Button2");
button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
panel.add(button);

button = new JButton("Button3");
button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
panel.add(button);

add(panel);
```

Comment: this one is not compiling

Answer (score 7):

```
JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
testPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(testPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
/*add variables here and add them to testPanel
        e,g`enter code here`
        testPanel.add(nameLabel);
        testPanel.add(textName);
*/
testPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding a link to BoxLayout to your answer to improve it, and a short explanation.