# How to arrange multiple panels vertically?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to arrange the 4 panels so that each panel appears right below the panel above. Currently, the terminatePanel appears at the side of aptPanel but I want it to be below it.
Using border layout doesn't seem to work or I'm just doing it wrong. Are there other ways to do it?

```
add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(aptPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(terminatePanel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
add(endPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Here is what it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BoxLayout` or `FlowLayout` with to make what you want to happen.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510641/add-controls-vertically-instead-of-horizontally-using-flow-layout).