# How to create a dialog box with two questions

Tags: java, swing

I know how to create a simple dialog with "yes" or "no" buttons.

```
Object[] options = {"yes", "no"};

int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    gameView,
    "choose one",
    "Message",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    options,
    options[0]
);
```

But now I want to create a dialog with two questions. How do I do that?

I'd like the dialog to look like this:

[image: Dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really insert any content you want into a dialog. You are currently inserting a string ("choose one") but you could actually pass in an entire panel of controls:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a button group containing blue and red, with blue selected
        final ButtonGroup color = new ButtonGroup();
        final JRadioButton blue = new JRadioButton("Blue");
        final JRadioButton red  = new JRadioButton("Red");
        color.add(blue);
        blue.setSelected(true);
        color.add(red);

        // Create a button group containing triangle and square, with triangle selected
        final ButtonGroup shape = new ButtonGroup();
        final JRadioButton triangle = new JRadioButton("Triangle");
        final JRadioButton square   = new JRadioButton("Square");
        shape.add(triangle);
        triangle.setSelected(true);
        shape.add(square);

        // Create a panel and add labels and the radio buttons
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Choose a color:"));
        panel.add(blue);
        panel.add(red);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Choose a shape:"));
        panel.add(triangle);
        panel.add(square);

        // Show the dialog
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null /*gameView*/, panel, "Message",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
        );

        // Print the selection
        if (blue.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Blue was selected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Red was selected");
        }

        if (triangle.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("Triangle was selected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Square was selected");
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a popup which looks like this:

[image: Dialog]

It doesn't look exactly like your image but that falls outside the scope of your question. If you want to change that, you'll need to play around with different types of layout. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534889/how-to-make-jlabels-start-on-the-next-line) for starters.